# Constructions that can be seen as objects representing a functor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, representable-functors

Some constructions can be seen as objects representing a functor.

For example,

- Consider a topological group $G$ and a functor $\mathcal{F}:\text{Top}\rightarrow \text{Gpd}$ defined as $M\mapsto \mathcal{F}(M)$ where $\mathcal{F}(M)$ is the category of principal $G$-bundles over $M$ (whose objects are principal $G$-bundles over $M$ and morphisms are $G$-equivariant maps that induce identity on base spaces). Here, $\text{Top}$ is with morphisms as homotopy classes of continuous maps. **In case this functor $\mathcal{F}$ is representable**, then, we should  get an object $\mathcal{F}_G$ of $\text{Top}$, that is a topological space, such that $\mathcal{F}(M)\cong \text{Hom}(M,\mathcal{F}_G)$ for each $M$ in $\text{Top}$. Then it is understood that this is  a representable functor and **the object of $\text{Top}$ representing this functor is denoted by $BG$**, called the classifying space of $G$. I see many times that same can be said about $G$ being Lie group, but, I am not very confident about this, so, not saying anything more.
- Consider a commutative ring $R$ and $R$-modules $M,N$ with a functor $\mathcal{F}:R\text{-Mod}\rightarrow \text{Set}$ defined as $Q\mapsto \mathcal{F}(Q)$ where $\mathcal{F}(Q)$ is the set of bilinear maps $M\times N\rightarrow Q$. **In case this functor $\mathcal{F}$ is representable**, then, we we should  get an object  get an $R$-module $\mathcal{F}_{M,N}$ such that $\mathcal{F}(Q)\cong \text{Hom}(\mathcal{F}_{M,N},Q)$ for each $Q$ in $R\text{-Mod}$. Then, it is understood that this functor is rep. and **the object of $R\text{-Mod}$ representing this functor is denoted by $M\otimes_RN$**,  called the tensor product of $M$ and $N$.
- Consider the category $\mathcal{C}$ of CW complexes with morphisms as homotopy classes of continuous maps and a functor $\mathcal{F}^n:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \text{Set}$ defined as $M\mapsto \mathcal{F}^n(M)$, where $\mathcal{F}^n(M)$ is the set underlying the cohomology group $H^n(M,\mathbb{Z})$. **In case this functor $\mathcal{F}^n$ is representable**, then, we should get an object $\mathcal{F}^n_n$ of $\mathcal{C}$, that is a CW comple, such that $\mathcal{F}^n(M)=\text{Hom}(M,\mathcal{F}^n_n)$ for each $M$ in $\mathcal{C}$. Then, it is understood that this is a representable functor and **the object of $\mathcal{C}$ representing this functor is denoted by $K(\mathbb{Z},n)$**, called the Eilenberg-Maclane space of degree $n$.

Are there any other such constructions that can be introduced using the notion of representable functor. There is a restriction of maximum 5 tags, but constructions from any field are welcome.

As mentioned by Laurent Moret-Bailly, Dmitri Pavlov most constructions in category theory can be expressed in terms of Representable functors. I am looking for some non trivial examples, I do not have any precise definition of "non trivial" yet.

Comment: Any "universal property" can be expressed in terms of a representable functor, so I wouldn't know where to start, or where  to stop.

Comment: A probable example would be the finite category of graphs and the functor consisting of graph homomorphisms. May be it would be representable. Or consider the category of quivers

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly I am not able to fill details immediately but I do agree there is a close relation between "universal property" and representable functors... Thank you for the comment.. I will try to make my question more sensible...

Comment: @vidyarthi what does it mean to say "functor consisting of graph morphisms" or "consider the category of quivers"? what exactly is the functor, from where to where? what object represents that functor?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I meant the functor is from the category of graphs to the category of the sets  defined by the graph being mapped to its set of homomorphisms/ group of homomorphisms. By "consider the category of quivers", I meant  to consider the the free category of quivers instead of the category of graphs

Comment: @vidyarthi Oh...So, the functor is the forgetful functor..  I will try to see if this is representable and which objects represents it...

Comment: The first and third examples are incorrect as stated.  Top is a category, so the set of morphisms M→F_G cannot be equivalent (let alone isomorphic) to a groupoid.  The third example suffers from a similar mistake: one must take homotopy classes of maps, so this will not be a representable functor on Top.

Comment: Concerning the general question: almost all definitions in category theory can be expressed using representable functors, including limits (such as products, pullback, equalizers), colimits (such as coproducts, pushouts, coequalizers), left and right adjoint functors, ends and coends, left and right Kan extensions, etc.  So the question, quite literally, asks to list a substantial fraction of mathematics.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Yes, I should have taken homotopy classes in first case.. In third case, I mean homotopy class of maps, I did not mention, should have mentioned... I am looking for some constructions which are not  obvious cases of limits, colimits etc. Does this question then have some non trivial answer?

Comment: I see a downvote... any suggestion on improving the question?